# No grub bootload show when I turn on computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-8

I am new in Ubuntu. This is my first time experience.

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot; but, when I turn on computer, it directly opens with Ubuntu. There is no Windows 8 option and here is also no grub bootloader option coming up.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you still have Windows installed?

Comment: If Windows 8 pre-installed it is UEFI, did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` terminal command.

Comment: i am sure i have still windows 8 ,in my hard drive .

Comment: So post the `sudo parted -l` and we'll see.

Comment: Model: ATA ST1000LM048-2E71 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  107GB   107GB  primary   ntfs
 2      107GB   703GB   596GB  extended               lba
 5      107GB   406GB   298GB  logical   ntfs
 6      406GB   703GB   297GB  logical   ntfs
 3      703GB   704GB   300MB  primary   fat32        boot, esp
 4      704GB   1000GB  297GB  primary   ext4

Answer (score 0):

Open `/etc/default/grub` for editing (you will probably need to run with sudo for write permission).  Edit the following lines:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
```

The first line will show the grub menu on boot, which will hopefully have an option for booting to Windows.  The `GRUB_TIMEOUT` parameter is the number of seconds to wait for a selection before using the default.  You could adjust this to your liking.

After you make the change in `/etc/default/grub`, you will have to run `update-grub` (again, probably with sudo) to apply the changes.  Then reboot and make sure the grub menu appears.

If you get the grub menu to appear, but still do not see an entry for Windows, then I suggest you edit your question to reflect this.